# Gdb dump memory in specific region, save formatted output into a file

Tags: memory-leaks, gdb, dump, coredump

I have a buggy (memory leaked) software.
As an evidence, I have 1GB of core.dump file.  Heap size is 900MB, so obviously, something allocates, but does not free the memory.

So, I have a memory region to examine like this.

```
(gdb) x/50000s 0x200000000
```

However, this is hard to guess only with naked eyes, which object or struct is not freed.
My idea to trace is, "Save gdb formatted output into a file, and run a pattern match to see which magic string comes up the most."  So, here is my question:

How can I save output of following command into a textfile, so that I can write an analyzer?

```
(gdb) x/10000000s 0x20000000    <-- I need this output into a file
```

Answer (score 72):

You could use the "dump" function of gdb, see: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html

For your example:

```
dump binary memory result.bin 0x200000000 0x20000c350
```

This will give you a plain binary dump int file `result.bin`. You can also use the following to dump it in hex format:

```
dump ihex memory result.bin 0x200000000 0x20000c350
```

Using the dump command is much clearer than using the gdb logging hack (which even did not work for me somehow).

Answer (score 19):

> How can I save output of following command into a textfile, so that I can write an analyzer?
>
> ```
>  (gdb) x/10000000s 0x20000000
> ```

That's actually quite easy:

```
(gdb) set height 0    # prevent GDB from stopping every screenfull
(gdb) set logging on  # GDB output is now also copied into gdb.txt
(gdb) x/10000000s 0x20000000
(gdb) quit
```

Voila, enjoy your output in `gdb.txt`.

> I have a buggy (memory leaked) software. ... "Save gdb formatted output into a file, and run a pattern match to see which magic string comes up the most."

That idea is quite unlikely to yield satisfactory results. Consider:

```
void some_function() {
   std::vector<string> *v = new std::vector<string>();
   // code to insert and use 1000s of strings into "v".
   return;  // Oops: forgot to delete "v".
}
```

Even if you could effectively "see magic string that comes up the most", you'll discover that you are leaking all the strings; but they are *not* the problem, leaking "v" is the problem.

So what you really want is to build a graph of which allocated regions point to other allocated regions, and find a "root" of that graph. This is nearly impossible to do by hand.

So what is *more* likely to help you find the memory leak(s)? Fortunately, there are *lots* of tools that can solve this problem for you:

- [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org),
- Google heap leak [checker](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/heap_checker.html),
- [jemalloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/jemalloc),
- ... etc. etc.

Comment: There is also a dedicated dump command in gdb.
See also: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Dump_002fRestore-Files.html

Answer (score -3):

you can write simple lkm will do that

```
lkm:
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

int  *ptr=(int*)0Xc18251c0; //the address you want to read from kernel space
int module_i(void)
{
 printk("%d\n",*ptr);
}
module_init(module_i);
```

and the data will show up in log
so write

```
enter code here
dmesg
```

Comment: You can just use /dev/kmem or /proc/kcore to do that. Furthurmore, this does not answer the question.